# \cite without bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, citing, bibitem

I am using `TeXShop` and I have a small references section that looks good when it renders as per a `\bibitem` for each reference. Is there a way to include citations in the main text without resorting to a bibtex file?

I have tried `\cite{}` but it doesn't seem to make a difference what I put in the curly braces; I just get "?" in the brackets.

Comment: If you produce your `\bibitem`s for `thebibliography` manually, there is no need for BibTeX and `.bib` files. Usually `\bibitem` has one argument that can be used in `\cite`, for example: `\bibitem{sigfridsson} E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde: Some Chemistry Title, J. Chem. 1998` will be cited as `\cite{sigfridsson}`. Can you add a short example document that shows what you are doing to the question (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Note that you have to compile your document at least twice to see the correct reference in the citations.

Comment: The argument of a `\cite` instruction must correspond to the mandatory argument of a `\bibitem` instruction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The argument of every `\cite` instruction -- the "citation key" -- in the body of the document must correspond exactly to the mandatory argument of a `\bibitem` instruction in the `thebibliography` environment. (`\bibitem` can also have an optional argument. If the `\bibitem` statements don't have optional arguments, LaTeX will form numeric-style citation call-outs.) And, be sure to run LaTeX twice.

Here's an MWE (minimum working example) involving two `\cite` instructions and two `\bibitem` statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\cite{aa}, \cite{bb}

\begin{thebibliography}{2}

\bibitem{aa} Anna Anderegg, 2019, Thoughts.

\bibitem{bb} Brenda Bradshaw, 2018, Worries.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```