# Bib styles without BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies, amsart, bibitem

Within an `amsart` document, you can add a bibliography without a BibTeX file, by directly use the `\bibitem` command inside a `begin{thebibliography}` clause. See e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514635/79639).

Had I used BibTeX, I could also use the `bibliographystyle{alpha}` to change the style. This does not work in the direct citation format using `bibitem`. Is there a way to enforce a style on the first option?

Also [related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233655/changing-thebibliography-style) , but was asked over 5 years ago without a direct solutions.

Comment: I think the answer is there's no way, except for the accepted answer in the question you link to.

Comment: A manual `\bibitem` is simply you decided on the formatting yourself, that's rather the point

Comment: all bibtex does is write the `thebibliography` environment for you in a style as specified by the bibstyle. If you choose to write the items yourself, then you have full control over the style.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if so, can I decide on the style of the bullits (e.g., have `[AS00]` for a reference instead of `[3]`)?

Comment: @AmirSagiv there is no automation, you can have any label you like `\bibitem[zzzwibble]{zzz}  any text for this reference`

Comment: A main point of BibTeX is that it permits applying many different bibliography styles (contained in .bst files) to one and the same set of bibliographic entries (contained in .bib files). This is rather convenient if you publish papers with various journals and book publishers, especially if they provide their own .bst files. OTOH, if -- BIG IF!! -- you are certain that you will never, ever have to switch bibliography styles, it's almost certainly not worth learning BibTeX's procedures. Instead, just create `thebibliography` environments *by hand* for each and every one of your papers.

Answer (score 1):

The easy method to change the style of bibliography made with a  `thebibliography` environment:

1. Remove the bibliography (yes, the whole `thebibliography` environment).
2. Now make the bibliography with bibtex, with the style that you want.
3. Compile and verify that the references look OK in the PDF.
4. Replace the  `\bibliography{...}` and `\bibliographystyle{...}`  lines by the whole content of the  auxiliar `.bbl` file, that is just a new `thebibliography` environment.
5. Ready! Now you can send to the journal a single `.tex` file than can be compiled only with pdflatex, xelated or lualatex, without using bibtex.

The hard method to change the style of a `thebibliography` environment:

1. Edit each `\bibitem` manually. It could be a good option if there are only a few references. If thi is not the case, good look ...