# Simple bibliography without biblatex

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I have a document template that as a table containing the "Applicable Documents"

```
\subsection{Applicable Documents}
            \begin{xltabular}{1.0\textwidth}{p{0.025\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}Xp{0.075\textwidth}}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Ref}            & \textbf{Document Type}        & \textbf{Document Number}  & \textbf{Name}                             & \textbf{Rev.}         \\ \midrule
                [1]     & Specification                 & n/a                       & Any Document        & 20221112              \\
                \bottomrule
                \caption{Applicable Documents}
                \label{tab:applicable-documents}
            \end{xltabular}
```

What is the best way to turn the `[1]` into a referencable label similar to `bibitem{labeltext}` that when referenced, similar to `\cite{labeltext}` will in return again produce a `[1]`? I think it's too complicated for my case to create a custom bibliography style, so I thought there might be a simple approach using enumerated labels. But I couldn't figure out how to achieve that.

Update: I tried what has been proposed in the comments

```
\subsection{Applicable Documents}
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}%
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
        \begin{xltabular}{1.0\textwidth}{p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}Xp{0.075\textwidth}}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Ref}            & \textbf{Document Type}        & \textbf{Document Number}  & \textbf{Name}     & \textbf{Rev.}         \\ \midrule
            \bibitem{testkey}     & Specification                 & n/a                       & Any Document        & 20221112                    \\
            \bottomrule
            \caption{Applicable Documents}
            \label{tab:applicable-documents}
        \end{xltabular}
\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup
```

I end up with this, I think it's pretty close but my reference is somehow strange aligned in my table.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You can create the bibliography manually, see for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References.

Comment: There are some questions about this on the site here, for example [\cite without bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514635/cite-without-bibtex)

Comment: updated question

Comment: The updated code is not really implemented according to the proposed duplicate. The idea is that you have a separate `thebibliography` environment at the bottom of the document that only contains `\bibitem` statements containing the references and nothing else, and in the middle of the document you use `\cite` commands to refer to those bibitems. The `\cite` commands can be used in a table as you did here, but the `thebibliography` environment at the end of the document should be fairly simple with only minimal formatting (no tables and such).

Comment: I see, but can I then have like `thebibliography` hidden? Because I only want the `Applicable Documents` printed in the document and not an extra bibliography

Comment: Ok, I understand your request better now. In that case something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4021/how-to-set-a-marker-counter-label-to-an-arbitrary-piece-of-text seems applicable.